# Rounding number from XML to Excel

Tags: xml, excel, powershell, rounding, excel.application

I'm reading some value from XML:

```
<DocumentSetNumber>20151027301060001</DocumentSetNumber>

$DSN = $xml.metaBI.DocumentSetNumber
```

and then writing to Excel using PowerShell:

```
$ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row,1).Value2 = $DSN
```

But in Excel I'm getting this number: 2.0151E+16

If I change Excel format I can get this: 20151027301060000

It's not the same number, and I need to get exactly the same.

I tried to play with Excel formats and also use Tostring() on variable, but without luck.

What also can I try?

PS. If I copy and paste this value manually it works only I use

> match destination formatting

option in Excel.

How I can set this option from PowerShell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to have to put this long DSN into the cell as a string. Excel has a [15 digit precision](http://blogs.office.com/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/) and rounds off any numbers longer than 15 digits to the nearest placeholder.

Given your code, it seems that prefacing the `$DSN` with a single quote (e.g. `'` or ASCII 039) as a [Range.PrefixCharacter property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.prefixcharacter.aspx) should suffice. Alternately, you could change the number format of the receiving cell to **Text** but I think a forced prefix character is best. Since a single quote (aka *tick*) is used as a quoting operator in PowerShell, we need to bring it in as a `[char]39`.

```
$tic = [char]39
$DSN = $xml.metaBI.DocumentSetNumber
$ExcelWorkSheet.Cells.Item($Row,1).Value2 = $tic + $DSN
# write-host $tic$dsn <~~ this outputs correctly but apparently not correct for XL cell value. see comments.
```

That should change `20151027301060001` to `'20151027301060001` and Excel will accept it as string text without trying to force it into a number.

Comment: Thanks for clarify what actually works. I didn't set up a complete XL test bench and relied on `write-host $tic$dsn` which seemed to be sending out the correct concatenated string. I will adjust my answer above to suit your experience.